# Import multiple files in R - not working with fread

Tags: r, data.table, fread

So, I have a directory with several *.gd files and I want to import all of them efficiently, in a way that I can work with them all later. I tried this:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
files <- list.files("C:/Users/marlichimi/Desktop/ALL_SAMPLES", pattern="*.gd", full.names=TRUE)
all_samples <- lapply(filenames,fread)
```

but 'fread' keeps giving me an error message.

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
>     Expecting 3 cols, but line 25 contains text after processing all cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having embedded sep=';' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes. fread cannot handle such ambiguous cases and those lines may not have been read in as expected. Please read the section on quotes in ?fread.

The sep in my tables is "/t". I tried one of the samples with read.table to see if it was working and it works. Anyone knows what's the problem or if there's another way to do this?

Comment: [As far as I've read the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf), `fread{data.table}` does not read files with `.gd` extension. Could you somehow convert those files into `.csv` format ?

Comment: Try `lapply(filenames,fread, sep = "\t")`

Comment: @RafaelPereira If `read.table` can read it, `fread` should read it too. As long as it is a textfile `fread` doesn't care about filename extensions.

Comment: @Roland, thanks for the heads up !

Comment: @Roland i tried that and gave me an erro again: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'sep' must be 'auto' or a single character